# Rails activeRecord to create a record but with some conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to create 500 random records in Table Followship with lib/dev:fake and the

condition is user_id != followship_id.

Followship has these columns [id, user_id, following_id, ....]

here's my code

```
500.times do |i|

  followship = Followship.new(        
    user: User.all.sample,
    following: User.all.sample
  )
  if followship.user_id != followship.following_id
    followship.save!     
  end
end
```

Apparently, it's wrong. But how do I fix this and make sure there're exactly 500

random records without duplicated?

Hope someone can help me.... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
500.times do |i|
  user = User.all.sample
  following = (User.all - [user]).sample

  Followship.create(        
    user: user,
    following: following
  )
end
```